# run the savina code https://github.com/shamsimam/savina

Tags: java, scala

I run the code in the GitHub project https://github.com/shamsimam/savina
   and after creating the jar file with:

```
java -jar savina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and try to execute the test I get this message

> no main manifest attribute, in Savina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

if anyone can run the test and told me where is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Savina repo doesn't contain a single file that can run all benchmarks. You have to run each benchmark separately like below

```
$ java -cp target/savina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.rice.habanero.benchmarks.concdict.DictionaryHabaneroRWArrivalOrderBenchmark

$ java -cp target/savina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.rice.habanero.benchmarks.facloc. FacilityLocationAkkaActorBenchmark
```

and so on. You can find the list of all different types of benchmarks on [this folder](https://github.com/shamsimam/savina/tree/master/src/main/scala/edu/rice/habanero/benchmarks) and inside each folder they contain the implementation in each of the actor systems.

Answer (score 0):

Your jar-file doesn't include the manifect, where the class to launch is set, so you can't run it in with `java -jar`
Instead you should use the full name of the class to run. Here's an example

```
java -cp my-app.jar com.mycompany.app.App
```

The code launches a class `App.class` from the package `com.mycompany.app`.

Comment: I get this result                                                         
                 >/Desktop/savina-master/target$ java -cp savina-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar edu.rice.habanero.benchmarks.BenchmarkRunner' (Error: Main method not found in class edu.rice.habanero.benchmarks.BenchmarkRunner), please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application – –         @Michel_T.